# 404 logout with SpringMVC and SpringSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, logout

I am learning spring security (java based config) and I cannot make the logout work properly.  When I hit logout I see the URL changes to http://localhost:8080/logout and get the "HTTP 404 - /logout".  The login functionality works fine (even with custom login form) but the logout is the problem, I suspect the redirected url "localhost:8080/logout" should be like "localhost:8080/springtest/logout"

I am following a combination of a book and also these examples:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html

I am using:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is the MVC initializer:

```
    public class MvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootApplicationContextConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebApplicationContextConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new HiddenHttpMethodFilter() };
    }
 }
```

And this the Security Initializer:

```
    public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

This the Web config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.munilvc.springtest" })
public class WebApplicationContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    // Serve static content like <mvc:resources/> tags
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/magic/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

}
```

This is the security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Also have a home controller, I am not sure this is the best way to do it, but I want that localhost:8080/springtest redirects to home, and Spring security should intercept that with the login page.  This is working for me now but I wonder if this is the correct way to do that?

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String showLoginForm(Model model) {
    return "home";
  }

}
```

Finally, this is the logout in my home page:

```
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
            Signed in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">${pageContext.request.remoteUser}</a>

        <form class="navbar-form pull-right" action="/logout"
            method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" /> <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
        </form>
```

Do I need to do an explicit request mapping for logout? I have checking the sample app hellomvc-jc from spring docs, but I do not see any explicit request mapping, so I belive SpringSecurity 4 already takes care of that, isn't it?

Thank you very much! I really appreciate you time and I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `action="logout"` instead of `action="/logout"`

Comment: Thank you James Jithin, this worked!  I was pretty sure I tried that one but given the number of configurations/combinations I tried I am not sure at all.

My question is, why I see that the docs still use "/logout" instead of "logout"? I suspect this has to do with the view resolver or some request mapping?